# Best way to find out if IEnumerable<> has unique values

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a lot of code in which I do something like this

```
bool GetIsUnique(IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    return values.Count() == values.Distinct().Count;
}
```

Is there a better faster nicer way to do this?

Comment: Typo: you capitalized "Values" in your method body, but your parameter is lower case.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your method needs to iterate through the sequence twice, with a few of potential drawbacks:

1. Iterating twice will be slower than iterating once for sequences of any significant size.
2. Some sequences will throw an exception if you try to iterate them more than once; others might return different results for subsequent iterations.
3. Your method uses `Count` which needs to iterate the entire sequence each time. There's no reason why you shouldn't break-out early as soon as you know that there's a duplicate value.

The following method only needs to iterate through the sequence once, and will break-out early as soon as any duplicate value is encountered:

```
bool GetIsUnique<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    var set = new HashSet<T>();

    foreach (T item in values)
    {
        if (!set.Add(item))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 22):

I would make this a nice extension method

```
public static bool IsUnique<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list)
{
    var hs = new HashSet<T>();
    return list.All(hs.Add);  
}
```

Checks that all items can be added to a HashSet.

Comment: +1 Using the hs.Add as the parameter is very beautiful (if only a little unreadable). (and put a space between var and hs)

Comment: Nice answer, even if a bit terse :)

Comment: I don't like having a predicate to `All` with side effects.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @CodeInChaos, LINQ methods are not supposed to cause side effects...

Comment: The side effect is pretty irrelevant. The hashset is thrown away after exiting the method.

Comment: I didn't say it was incorrect, only that it's bad style. For example imagine an implementation of `All` that memoizes the the result of the predicate. That'd break your code.

Comment: but.... the implementation of `All` *doesn't* memorize the result. Are you seriously considering a malicious implementation of All? holy cow.

Comment: I think this example of code is important because it shows that you don't need to do list.All(p => hs.Add(p)) (that would have been much more readable, I'll add) when the method you want to use has the same "signature" you need.

Comment: @Jamiec "but.... the implementation of All doesn't memorize the result." That by itself is irrelevant. The implementation is by definition an implementation detail. The question is: Does the *contract* of `All` *guarantee* to work with a predicate that has side-effects. --- Granted it's unlikely that future versions of linq-to-objects will break your code. But it already won't work with ordered parallel linq. And IMO memoization is a valid optimization in a functional programming library such as linq. So I would not consider such an implementation malicious.

Comment: And there are linq methods were having side effects in the predicate can result in different behavior between Mono and .net.

Comment: I can see the point of CodeInChaos... For those that don't know what Memoization is (and there is a good wiky for it), let's say that All could be implemented as `return list.Distinct().Any(p => !condition)`. It would be ok from the POV of the contract, but it would break THIS implementation. The problem with this "game" is that there are probably more classes "lightly" defined than classes completely defined in C#.

Comment: This concern isn't valid at all. The `All` method says it 'tests all elements of the sequence'. In other words, it's not treating it as a set. It must test the predicate on every element, in order. As soon as an element in the sequence returns false, break and return false. The implementation of the predicate is irrelevant. The implementation `list.Distinct().Any(p=>!condition)` would break the contract of `All`, because that would not in fact test "All" elements of the sequence. `All` must test all elements of the sequence, regardless of whether they are the same or not.

Answer (score 6):

I think it depends on what you want to do if there are non unique values. @Jamiec's Or @LukeH's answer are great answers and probably best for pure speed, but it can't tell you where issues are.

You might also consider something like

```
var group = values.GroupBy(x => x);
return group.Any(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

On it's own its worse than the `HashSet` implementation. But if you keep that group around you can find which elements are duplicated.

```
var group = values.GroupBy(x => x);
return group.Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

Or

```
var group = values.GroupBy(x => x);
return group.Where(g => g.Count() > 1).Select(g => g.Key);
```

Thinking about it with `GroupBy` lets you keep your options open for what to do next. But if all you care about is knowing if all values are unique I'd go with the `HashSet`

Comment: @digEmAll: Using `GroupBy` requires that the entire sequence is iterated before you can start testing for duplicates, which could be a problem when dealing with longer sequences. (The `HashSet<T>` implementations can break-out as soon as the first dupe is found.)

Comment: @LukeH - Yup, `HashSet` will always be faster if you just want to answer the question "Are there duplicates?". I'm just trying to point out that if you are going to follow up with "What are the duplicates?" or "How many duplicates are there?" then it is worth considering using `GroupBy` because you can ask it all of those questions.

Comment: @Mike: But using `GroupBy` for the initial query doesn't give you any advantage. The query will be re-evaluated each time you use it, so why not use `Intersect` for the initial test and then `GroupBy` for any subsequent queries, if you need them?

Comment: @LukeH: We are doing something similar on my current project. For us one of the big costs is the equality comparison and `GetHashCode` calls. With the `GroupBy` called once we only pay that cost for one loop through the original collection. What we do is call `GroupBy`, `Select` the groups with more than one element and call `ToList` on that. We then do a lot of work on the groups with duplicates. Not claiming this is right in all situations. Just trying to give an alternative and reasons to consider it. Either way performance should be measured for your actually situation.

Comment: @Mike: Fair enough, but the examples in your answer *don't* do that. The `group` variable is a description of a query, not a set of results, so every time `group` is used then the `GroupBy` query will be executed again.

Comment: @LukeH: Great point. I oversimplified in the answer. I'll put in a more complete version to clarify. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @LukeH: yes of course it evaluates all the the list, so it's slower (excluding the worst-case)... but as stated by mike if you need to know which are the duplicates this allows it (obviously you need to save the query)...

Answer (score 1):

You would be doing two loops through the data for the above - once to get the count, once to get the distinct count. Especially bad if the first two items are identical! Try something like this:

```
bool GetIsUnique<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
{
    HashSet<T> hashSet = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach(var value in values)
    {
        if (hashSet.Contains(value))
        {
            return false;
        }
        hashSet.Add(value);
    }
    return true;
}
```

This one will finish as soon as it finds a duplicate. Obviously it on the speed of the hash lookup but given Distinct uses a set internally I'd still expect it to be quicker.

Comment: Surely you can speed this up by merging the HashSet Contains and Add into one step?

Comment: Yeah, obvious now you say it! I was clearly thinking in terms of a dictionary and not a set...

Answer (score 0):

Two basic rules:

1. The easiest way to read and understand is almost always the best way to code something.  That code is deliciously easy to read, so I'd say you're good to go.
2. Performance ("faster") should only be a concern if you can prove that *this* is the method that's slowing your program down, or if you're building a library that other people will have access to without having access to the source code.

The other methods are going to be faster (they'll short circuit when a repeated value is found, returning false), but, I'd still stick with your version if it were my code.

Comment: The pre-eminent rule should be that "Correctness is more important than either readability or performance"; if your code is broken then it doesn't matter how beautiful or performant it is. The code in the question is (theoretically) broken because not all sequences support being iterated more than once.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way of finding the first duplicate, if present, is:

```
public static bool TryFindFirstDuplicate<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, out T duplicate)
{
    var set = new HashSet<T>();
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (!set.Add(item))
        {
            duplicate = item;
            return true;
        }
    }
    duplicate = default(T);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm suprised no one has tested this just yet:

Comparing Gluip's version in the question with JamieC, LukeK, and MrKWatkins, All three answers are better than the asker's version.

Of the three answers, they are all pretty comparable but in most case JamieC's is slightly faster.

When the data has no duplicates or a duplicate is at the end of the IEnumerable, the size or algorithm had no major differences.

When the data has a duplicate near the middle, or at the beginning, Gluip's version in the original question shows its slowness compared to the other three.

The time to check a set appears to scale linearly with the size of set, meaning no algorithm is preferable for large or small sets.

Here's a test program that spits out a CSV that you can load into a spreadsheet program and sort and graph if you like:

Test Program:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AreUniqueTest
{
class Program
{
    const int Iterations = 1000;

    enum DupeLocation
    {
        None,
        Early,
        Center,
        Late,
    }

    enum SetSize
    {
        Tiny= 10,
        Small = 100,
        Medium = 1000,
        Large = 10000,
        Huge = 100000,
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<int>, bool>> functions = new Dictionary<string, Func<IEnumerable<int>, bool>>
        {
            {"Gluip", GetIsUniqueGluip},
            {"LukeH", GetIsUniqueLukeH },
            {"Jamiec", GetIsUniqueJamiec },
            {"MrKWatkins", GetIsUniqueMrKWatkins }
        };

        var output = new StringBuilder();

        Console.WriteLine("Function,SetSize,DupeLocation,TotalTicks,AverageTicks");
        output.AppendLine("Function,SetSize,DupeLocation,TotalTicks,AverageTicks");

        foreach (SetSize size in Enum.GetValues(typeof(SetSize)))
        {
            var sizevalue = (int) size;
            foreach (DupeLocation location in Enum.GetValues(typeof(DupeLocation)))
            {
                var data = CreateTestData((int)size, location);
                foreach (string functionKey in functions.Keys)
                {
                    var ticks = RunSet(functions[functionKey], data, Iterations);
                    var avg = ticks / Iterations;
                    Console.WriteLine($"{functionKey},{sizevalue},{location},{ticks},{avg}");
                    output.AppendLine($"{functionKey},{sizevalue},{location},{ticks},{avg}");
                }
            }
        }

        File.WriteAllText("output.csv", output.ToString());
        Process.Start("output.csv");
    }

    static long RunSet<T>(Func<IEnumerable<T>, bool> getIsUnique, IEnumerable<T> values, int iterations)
    {
        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
            getIsUnique.Invoke(values);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();
        return stopwatch.ElapsedTicks;
    }

    static bool GetIsUniqueLukeH<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        var set = new HashSet<T>();

        foreach (T item in values)
        {
            if (!set.Add(item))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    static bool GetIsUniqueGluip<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        return values.Count() == values.Distinct().Count();
    }

    static bool GetIsUniqueJamiec<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
    {
        var hs = new HashSet<T>();
        return list.All(hs.Add);
    }

    static bool GetIsUniqueMrKWatkins<T>(IEnumerable<T> values)
    {
        HashSet<T> hashSet = new HashSet<T>();
        foreach (var value in values)
        {
            if (hashSet.Contains(value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            hashSet.Add(value);
        }
        return true;
    }

    static int[] CreateTestData(int size, DupeLocation location)
    {
        var result = new int[size];
        Parallel.For(0, size, i => { result[i] = i; });
        return SetDupe(result, location);
    }

    static int[] SetDupe(int[] values, DupeLocation location)
    {
        switch (location)
        {
            case DupeLocation.Early:
                values[1] = values[0];
                break;
            case DupeLocation.Center:
                var midpoint = values.Length / 2;
                values[midpoint] = values[midpoint + 1];
                break;
            case DupeLocation.Late:
                values[values.Length - 1] = values[values.Length - 2];
                break;
            // case DupeLocation.None: // do nothing.
        }
        return values;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: For my own purposes, I want to check uniqueness to validate input, so almost every the time the code is called I expect to get sets that contain no duplicates. more than 99.99% of the time there would be no performance benefit for my use case. I actually went with .Count() == .Distinct().Count() with a comment, because this most clearly communicates the intention of the code.